# wifi connection activation issue in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am unable to connect to a particular Wi-Fi router, though I can connect to my phone's Wi-Fi if I make a hotspot or to any other Wi-Fi.

It is not the Wi-Fi router's issue as I can connect other devices to the same router, and I was connected to the same router with Ubuntu 18.04.